# avahi-resolve resolves hostname that dig -p 5353 @224.0.0.251 does not?

Tags: dig, avahi, mdns

I thought `avahi-resolve` and `dig -p 5353 @224.0.0.251` did much the same thing.

However, I have a device where I can resolve its name using `avahi-resolve` but not using `dig`:

```
$ avahi-resolve --name ding-5cd80b3.local
ding-5cd80b3.local  192.168.0.248

$ dig +short -p 5353 @224.0.0.251 ding-5cd80b3.local
;; Warning: ID mismatch: expected ID 60466, got 0
```

With neither can I do a reverse lookup:

```
$ avahi-resolve --address 192.168.0.248
Failed to resolve address '192.168.0.248': Timeout reached

$ dig +short -p 5353 @224.0.0.251 -x 192.168.0.248
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The device that's advertising its name is a simple IoT device so I'm not surprised that it has very basic mDNS support (if uses the [mDNS support](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/mdns.html) provided by the ESP-IDF).

I've tried using verbose flags with both `avahi-resolve` and `dig` to see if either would give me some insight into what's happening but in neither case did I get any extra insight.

I'm guessing that `ID mismatch` means that `dig` actually is getting a response but is refusing to show it as it's interpreting this as a case of [DNS spoofing](https://serverfault.com/a/475934/282515) while `avahi-resolve` is being more forgiving.

Is there any way to get `dig` to be more forgiving (I tried `+besteffort`) or any way I can see what's going on here, short of using Wireshark?

I'm working on Ubuntu and, as noted, the device in questions is using the [ESP-IDF](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does indeed seem to be with the underlying ESP-IDF library and its mDNS support.

It does not include the ID included in the original query in its response, it always just uses 0. Hence the `dig` error saying `ID mismatch: expected ID 60466, got 0`.

I've logged issue [#5574](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/5574) against the ESP-IDF to address this.